# "Access denied" for all users after reset of root password

Tags: centos, passwd

I updated a CentOS 7.3 based server to 7.4 today. After that my defined users were no longer able to `sudo`. Because something had messed up the root account months before I decided to reset the root password by using these steps:

- boot to grub, press `e`
- searched for the `linux` line and change `ro` to `rw init=/sysroot/bin/bash`
- pressed `Ctrl+X` to continue boot
- ran `chroot /sysroot`
- changed the password using `passwd`

After another reboot to boot regularly I still can't use the root account and I even get `Access denied` (using `ssh`)  or `Login incorrect` when using the physical console.

Any ideas ?  I am basically locked out of that server

Comment: I assume you can't check auth log either for more specific error message. You probably need to use the same `init=/bin/bash` method as before to  get more information (and fix the issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ran the passwd command, it edited the /etc/shadow file to update the password while selinux wasn't running so it messed up your selinux permissions. To fix this use the same process and instead of `passwd` run
`touch /.autorelabel`, then reboot. Beware that your first boot can potentially consume a lot of time, depending on amount of files and speed of drives.

This will relabel the entire filesystem to use the default selinux contexts. You could also use [restorecon](https://linux.die.net/man/8/restorecon) instead.

Comment: I am now at least able to do what I was able to do before: log in as a regular user. I still can't do `sudo` or login as the root user, but this has to be due to a different reason.